# Get values from Json array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the value from this following JSON array in a PHP variable(named `$result`).

This is a `var_dump` of the array:

```
array(1) { [272]=>
    array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(13) { 
            ["actions"]=> array(0) { } 
            ["idle_timeout"]=> int(0) 
            ["cookie"]=> int(0) 
            ["packet_count"]=> int(0) 
            ["hard_timeout"]=> int(0) 
            ["byte_count"]=> int(0) 
            ["length"]=> int(80) 
            ["duration_nsec"]=> int(620000000) 
            ["priority"]=> int(10) 
            ["duration_sec"]=> int(4341) 
            ["table_id"]=> int(0) 
            ["flags"]=> int(0) 
            ["match"]=> array(4) { 
                ["dl_type"]=> int(2048) 
                ["nw_proto"]=> int(1) 
                ["nw_src"]=> string(11) "192.168.1.1" 
                ["nw_dst"]=> string(11) "192.168.1.2" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and I need to get the value from `["nw_proto"]`, `["nw_src"]`, `["nw_dst"]` and `["priority"]`, after I use `json_decode($result[0])` and `echo`, i got a `NULL(array?)`

could someone help me out of this array structure, it really confuses me...

Comment: can you try accessing the the elements directly with decoding it like `$result[0]` because its already an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$priority = $result[272][0]['priority'];  // priority
$nw_proto = $result[272][0]['match']['nw_proto'];  // nw_proto
$nw_src = $result[272][0]['match']['nw_src'];  // nw_src
$nw_dst = $result[272][0]['match']['nw_dst'];  // nw_dst
```

Comment: @鄔瑞瑞 Please show your gratitude by accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

use $result[272][0] to get to the values you need.

You could also use reset($result) if you always need the first element (in this case key 272) from the $result array.

Comment: so you mean echo $result[272][0][0] can get "action" ?